# Knockoutjs dynamically adding checkbox column to a table

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to dynamically add a column containing checkboxes to a table. Current Fiddle at 
http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/N5tQT/5/, which is heavily based on Ryan Niemeyer's example at 
http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/USjuY/82/. In the example, clicking Add Teacher adds a new row with the selected teacher, while clicking Add Asst adds a column with the selected assistant.

When I add an assistant, it reuses the activeColumn observable array to determine whether to add a readable or writable text input, but I'd like to be able to add a third type of column with checkboxes, something like the Checkbox1 column where the user can associate an assistant with a teacher, when desired. The checkbox column would contain something like:

```
<td><input class="center" style="height:18px;"type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I thought about maybe adding a new activeAssts observable array like the current activeColumns, but it would lose the total columns. I also thought above additional parameters to the activeColumns observable array, and that might work, but not sure how to only add the checkbox columns. TIA, Steve

Comment: It would help if you trim the code so only the relevant bits are left, and edit the question to inline the question (that way if the link rots this question can still be useful to future visitors).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - will try to simplify next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use an observable that is set to true when you want to display the checkbox column. You can then use visible binding to only show the checkbox row when the observable is true.

```
var ViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;

    self.rows = $.map(model.rows, function (row) { return new RowData(row); } );
    self.showCheckboxes = ko.observable(false);

    self.showCheckboxesClick = function () {
        self.showCheckboxes(true);
    };
};

var RowData = function (row) {
    var self = this;

    ko.utils.extend(self, row);    

    self.isChecked = ko.observable();
};

<button data-bind="click: showCheckboxesClick">Show checkboxes</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th data-bind="visible: showCheckboxes"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            <td data-bind="visible: $parent.showCheckboxes"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YSvu3/

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear, but you can add one or more assistants, and I don't know their names at run time. In the real implementation, there's departments and divisions and so we'll have around 70 - 80 assistants in the dropdown. However, there will never be more than 7 assistants, so I could prebuild the columns and maybe just retitle them with the assistant chosen, but I'm a Knockout newbie, so hope I can figure that out. Maybe that would be an unfortunate jQuery operation? Ex of dynamically building html table at http://jsfiddle.net/cmschick/hyHQW/ - maybe that's another option?

Comment: How should the type of column be decided? It sounds like you have write, read and checkbox columns

Comment: Good question. Actually, come to think of it, the teacher ID column could be hidden or contained in the observable array, as long as I can uniquely identify the teacher, we're good. And the teacher column doesn't actually need to be writable. I only need the assistant checkbox columns to be able to be checked. That probably makes it easier! Given that, this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/N5tQT/6/ solves my immediate question. Thanks!